# How to get the result of the 'for x in myresult: print(x[0])' into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, mysql-python

Basically when my SQL command gets data for the db it comes out like this [('admin',)]

for x in myresult:
        print(x[0])
I found out that this will print it out as admin which is how I want It but I need a it to be saved to a variable such as username

def login():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(

```
host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="password",
database="testdb",
)


username=input("Please Enter Your username:     ") 

mycursor = mydb.cursor()


mycursor.execute ("SELECT name FROM account_database WHERE name = 'admin' ")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresult)
mydb.commit()
mycursor.close()

for x in myresult:
    print(x[0])
```

Comment: I guess my question is how do I get the result of for x in myresult:
    print(x[0]) saved to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the values to a list.

```
final = []
for x in myresult:
    print(x[0])
    final.append(x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> ```
> for x in myresult:
>     print(x[0])
> ```

Following that, `x` is still in scope,
so you can use expressions involving `x` to your heart's content.

Suppose your favorite variable is `v`.
Then after the loop you could assign e.g.:

```
v = x[0]
```

A better way to express your looping would be with tuple unpacking:

```
for name, in myresult:
    print(name)

v = name
```

Here, we are unpacking a 1-tuple into the string variable `name`.
A fancier query requesting two columns might use: `for name, age in myresult:`

Now, your current query uses an equality test
so it will return zero or one rows
(and the `v` assignment would fail in the zero-row "not found" case).
Imagine that instead of finding just `'admin'`
your WHERE clause asked for *all* names starting with `a`:

```
... WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
```

Then it would be more appropriate to gather up a **list** of names:

```
import pprint
...
names = [name
         for name, in myresult]

pprint.pprint(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `myresult` you obtained from `myresult = mycursor.fetchall()` is a list of tuples.

With `for x in myresult:`, `x` gets assigned each tuple from `myresult`, one after the other. And with `x[0]` you then access the first element in those tuples.

In your case, there is only one tuple, with only one value. This makes sense because your SQL selects the `name` from all records that have the name `'admin'` - you're basically checking if there are users with the name `'admin'`. It's unclear why you want to get this name, since it will be `'admin'` for every record though.

You could access it directly like this:

```
admin_name = myresult[0][0]
```

i.e. assign the first value from the first record in `myresult` to `admin_name`, but it would either be the same as `admin_name = 'admin'` or it would generate an error message if there is no user named `'admin'` in the database.

To check for that:

```
if len(myresult) == 0:
    print('There is no user named \'admin\'')
else:
    print('There is a user named \'admin\')
```

Note: if you're only interested to see if there are any records with that name, you don't need `.fetchall()` either, you could just use `.fetchone()`. Or you could even just run a query that avoids errors altogether:

```
mycursor.execute ("SELECT COUNT(name) FROM account_database WHERE name = 'admin'")
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
print(f'There are {myresult[0]} users named \'admin\'')
```